# Add button not working

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am trying to generate a tree structure. The '+' button adds a new level and the '-' removes the current level.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Editor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Editor</legend>
        <div class="pair">
        <input type="text" class="key" placeholder="key"></input>:<input type="text" class="value" placeholder="value"></input>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="+"/>
        <input type="button" class="delete" value="-"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("document").on('click','.pair .add',function(event){  
            event.target.parent().children("input.value").hide();
            var insert = '<div class="pair">'+
            '<input type="text" class="key" placeholder="key"></input>:<input type="text" placeholder="value">'+
            ' </input><input type="button" class="button" value="+"/>'+
            '<input type="button" class="delete" value="-"/>'+
            '</div>';
            event.target.parent().after(insert);
    });

    $("document").on('click','.pair .delete',function(){
            event.target.parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Both buttons are not working. I know the code inside .on('click',..) works because I used the same inside a $(".add").click() block which was working.
Am I missing something?Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `$(event.target).parent().after(insert);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pwuyq2f/) for you. First of all `$(document)`, not `$("document")`, second `event.target` selector was written wrong and your newly inserted elements had wrong classes

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Editor</legend>
        <div class="pair">
        <input type="text" class="key" placeholder="key"></input>:<input type="text" class="value" placeholder="value"></input>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="+"/>
        <input type="button" class="delete" value="-"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.pair .add',function(event){  

            $(this).parent().children("input.value").hide();
            var insert = '<div class="pair">'+
            '<input type="text" class="key" placeholder="key"></input>:<input type="text" placeholder="value" class="value">'+
            ' </input><input type="button" class="add" value="+"/>'+
            '<input type="button" class="delete" value="-"/>'+
            '</div>';
            $(this).parent().after(insert);
    });

    $(document).on('click','.pair .delete',function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: @user2522981 really? did you even check the other solutions provided?

Comment: @Anoop Joshi Thanks for your answer. However, I couldn't use it due to certain changes I made later. With respect to the original code, your answer would have definitely simplified it.:)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need create the html like this. You can use the clone() method to create the exact copy of the html elements. Then your code will be,

```
$(document).on('click', '.pair .add', function (event) {
    var pair = $(this).closest(".pair");
    pair.after(pair.clone());
});

$(document).on('click', '.pair .delete', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/161/)

Comment: One "gotcha", if the inputs have a value in them when you clone them, that input will appear in the clone. I like to cache the first element's html as a data attribute then use that to populate the rest to avoid that behavior

Comment: @DelightedD0D OP can tweak the code according to the need. He also can take the clone at the time of dom ready also. then there will not be any value inside that

Comment: Definitely, just wanted to mention it because it was something I had to figure out the first time I tried to do this : )

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this would be:

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/162/)

```
var $pair=$('.pair').eq(0);
var $pair.data('original',$pair[0].outerHTML);

$(document).on('click', '.pair .add', function (event) {
    var pair = $(this).closest(".pair");
    pair.after($($pair.data('original')));
});

$(document).on('click', '.pair .delete', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This is the same as Anoop's answer except it caches the clone html on load of the page to prevent input values being cloned with the elements

---

For your benefit, your original code had these issue:

1. `$("document")` should be `$(document)` without quotes
2. `'</input><input type="button" class="button" value="+"/>'+` should be `'</input><input type="button add" class="button" value="+"/>'+` you're missing the `add` class

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.pair .add', function (event) {
        $this = $(this);
        $parent = $this.parent();
        $parent.children(".value").hide();
        var insert = '<div class="pair">' +
            '<input type="text" class="key" placeholder="key"></input>:<input type="text" placeholder="value">' +
            ' </input><input type="button" class="button add" value="+"/>' +
            '<input type="button" class="delete" value="-"/>' +
            '</div>';
        $parent.after(insert);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.pair .delete', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Editor</legend>
            <div class="pair">
                <input type="text" class="key" placeholder="key"></input>:
                <input type="text" class="value" placeholder="value"></input>
                <input type="button" class="add" value="+" />
                <input type="button" class="delete" value="-" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) The corrections you suggested were right. However, @Gvidas gave them first.

Comment: No worries, @user2522981 , but you really should look at Anoop Joshi's answer and the bit I added to his above. While Gvidas's approach answered your question the fastest, you should really use this much simpler solution in your production code.